# WebRTC audio call on mobile using web app -- how to handle phone to ear?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, phone-call

I'm considering adding support for audio calls to my web app. I'm guessing WebRTC is the way to go. However, I am concerned with how this call will play out. Will it be necessary for the caller to hold the phone in front of him/her? If the caller places the phone to his/hers ear, the caller's ear might click some buttons on the user interface. Is there some elegant solution to this? As far as I know, there is no JavaScript API to disable the screen when the caller places the phone to his/hers ear. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: This will very much depend on the phone. Good phones consider this and will behave as expected by disabling the screen.

Comment: @deceze Do you know if this is it browser or OS dependent? I.e. does e.g. the chrome browser app receive information form the proximity sensor and then tells the OS to turn off the screen, or is this some default OS behaviour for ongoing audio calls?

Comment: I don't know too much about Android, but what I do know about iOS is that any call will necessarily go through the iOS audio/call infrastructure which incorporates this behaviour. Conceivably on Android this is more open to the individual browsers.

Comment: Currently a little dissuaded :) Testing with my fairly recent Android mobile on appr.tc, joining an empty room, and placing the phone to my ear, does not turn off the screen or disable it. But maybe someone needs to join the room. I'll test with a friend later.

Comment: Tested with a friend. Disabled video. Only audio active -- Android does not disable the screen, and my ear ends up clicking the user interface and interfers with the chrome tabs.